# How can remove read-only attribute from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a checkbox in a span tag  and input number. Initially the input number is read-only,   When the checkbox is being ticked,  remove the read only  attribute of the Input number  which is just close to  checkbox. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated

```
<tr>
    <td>
    <span><input type="checkbox"  asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsNormalAttendance" onclick="SetHrs(this);" /></span>
    <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" style="@(columnstyle);width: 5em"
                                       class="form-control format-text emphrs" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs"  />
    </td>
</tr>
    <script>
     function SetHrs(element) {
            var rowIndex = $(element).closest("tr").attr('id');      
           if ($(element).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=number]').removeAttr('readonly');   //  Not working
                
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: can you try .attr("readonly", false) instead of .removeAttr('readonly') and also in the html there is no tr so please check the html as well

Comment: There is already tr  in code but  i forgot to give before td here.  I given the  .attr("readonly", false), still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do more trouble than necessary to handle everything.

1. Don't mix javascript and jQuery. Try to keep everything as tidy as possible, creating sort of controllers for your page blocks. For example here you could have a *table controller*
2. It's a bit ugly trying to find elements by id, especially when using elements you expect to be repeated (such as rows). If you're sure that the *input* follows the *span*, you can use jQuery's `next` to get that element.

So in the following example what I did was:

1. Attaching the event listener using **event delegation** (removed the onclick attribute from the checkbox)
2. Getting the event target from the event argument
3. Finding the readonly input, using the suggestion above
4. Removing the readonly attribute, only when the checkbox is checked, so I did a little improvement, if you turn off the checkbox the *readonly* will be added again.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("table").on("change", "[name='foo']", function(e){
     const $target = $(e.target);
     const $targetInput = $target.parent().next();
     $targetInput[$target.is(":checked") ? "removeAttr" : "attr"]("readonly", "readonly");
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;  
}

input:read-only {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <span>
    <input name="foo" type="checkbox" />
  </span>
  <input type="number" readonly="readonly" placeholder="0.00" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```